# Android: using network service

Tags: android

I m using network service so when i click on button in my first activity , if it is dependent on network then on its click if the network is not available then its should give message that network not available and if network is available it should able to redirect to my  application.

So here i m sharing what problem i have

1> if network is available then i m calling intent from my main activity's button click event

mapbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

```
            if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                    connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ) {
            Toast.makeText(main.this,"You are:" + NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Do something in here when we are connected
            // call intent to go to map
            Intent intent = new Intent(main.this,HelloMap.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

}}

And in Else Condition i m displaying dialog that network connection unavailble...

HelloMap is my class which implements Map Functionality.

When i run my application it is giving error ...
classdefnotfound HelloMap.java.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this proble

i have include permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
include HelloMap class in manifest too..

Then also i m not getting proper output..

Can anybody help me.

Thanks Rakesh

```
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i run my application it is giving error ... classdefnotfound HelloMap.java.

Most likely, you are running on a device or emulator that does not have the Google APIs, and so does not have the `MapActivity` base class.

Comment: ok
thanks i have identified problem..
i was not using uses library google in manifest...
Anyway thanks for the effort